# Can't get specific element of API response [JS]

Tags: javascript, json, html

I can't seem to get a specific part out of the response below, using the code that is also below. I get an "undefined" in the console log when I try to use `response["minecraft.net"]`. Can someone explain to me why this isn't working?

Response:

```
"[{"minecraft.net":"green"},{"session.minecraft.net":"green"},{"account.mojang.com":"green"},{"auth.mojang.com":"green"},{"skins.minecraft.net":"green"},{"authserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"sessionserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"api.mojang.com":"green"},{"textures.minecraft.net":"green"},{"mojang.com":"green"}]"
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mojang Servives Status</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var api = new XMLHttpRequest();
api.open("GET", "https://status.mojang.com/check", false);
api.send();
console.log(api);
var response = JSON.parse(api.response)
console.log(response["minecraft.net"]);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Synchronous Ajax? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is wrapped inside of an array. So you'd use `response[0]['minecraft.net']`

Comment: @averysumner But keep in mind that this means you're assuming that the first index of the array always contains an object with the "minecraft.net" property. The way you're probably intended to consume this API is to loop through all of the array and display all of the properties alongside their values. Or if you're only interested in minecraft.net, loop through the array until you find that property (otherwise Mojang could change the order of the objects and your program will break)